# Errors in Mainactivity.java

Tags: java, android, eclipse, error-handling

I have the following code and I can't find a way to get rid of these errors:

> The method setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener) in the type View is not applicable for the arguments (MainActivity)

This applies to the lines 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25 containing:

```
findViewById(R.id.imageButton9).setOnClickListener(this);
```

In line 31 (the line where the new class is created), I get:

> The nested type MainActivity cannot hide an enclosing type

This is the code I'm working with:

```
package com.example.rome;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    findViewById(R.id.imageButton1).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.imageButton2).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.imageButton3).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.imageButton4).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.imageButton5).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.imageButton6).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.imageButton7).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.imageButton8).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.imageButton9).setOnClickListener(this);



}

class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
      switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.R.id.imagebutton1:
          startActivity(new Intent(telefoonnummers.class));
          break;
        case R.id.R.id.imagebutton2:
          startActivity(new Intent(telefoonnummers.class));
          break;
        //-- more cases --
        case R.id.R.id.imagebutton9:
              startActivity(new Intent(telefoonnummers.class));
              break;
      }
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

Comment: Why are you declaring MainActivity twice?

Comment: You really need to step back and become familiar with Java in general. Perhaps you should then proceed to becoming oriented with the Android SDK. There are absurd problems with your code.

Comment: I will do that, but can you please help me with the last error for now:The constructor Intent(Class<Telefoonnummers>) is undefined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the errant class definition:

```
class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
```

And add `implements View.OnClickListener` to the real class definition:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity  implements View.OnClickListener {
//      Add this to the "real" MainActivity ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Take a moment to make sure you have properly closed every brace (`{}`).

Comment: Thank you very much, but I stil get these then: 
The constructor Intent(Class<Telefoonnummers>) is 
R cannot be resolved or is not a field

Comment: @Ide `R.id.R.id.imagebutton2:` and friends should be just `R.id.imagebutton2:`, so take out the duplicate `R.id.`

Comment: Thank you, I think I will check all my other documents for duplication :p, do you also know what to do to get rid of the first error?: 
The constructor Intent(Class<Telefoonnummers>) is undefined

Comment: @Ide `startActivity(new Intent(telefoonnummers.class));` needs to be `startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, telefoonnummers.class));`